comparaison between numerical speed and theoretical speed
i have read the article " An Unconditionally Stable Difference Scheme for the
Two-Dimensional Modified
Fisher–Kolmogorov–Petrovsky–Piscounov Equation"  here is the link https://downloads.hindawi.com/journals/jmath/2023/5527728.pdf?_ga=2.164976063.1892242023.1716367174-1275339179.1715808341the author said that the theroretical speed of travelling waves of Fisher KPP equation in 2D is :$\frac{5}{\sqrt6}$ which is known and prouved previously  but then he compared with numerical speed and i didnt undertand how he get it ?and second thing he deal with u as function of 3variablles but u is function of 2variables? am i understanding wrong?

I don't think it is explicitly mentioned in the paper how the wave speed is computed numerically. However, the initial condition is the exact profile, so when you integrate it up to $T=8$, you can measure how far the profile shifted and divide by $T$ to get the numerical wave speed.

And the solution is a function of two space dimensions and time, hence 3 variables

@C.Hamstethanks for your answers for you first comment could you please explain more and for your second commment  but the function doesnt depend on y here i mean the exact solution

The fact that the exact solution does not depend on $y$ explicitly just indicates that the solution is constant in the $y$ directions, i.e. $u(x,y,t)=u(x,t)$ for all $y$. And for the speed of the wave, how would you intuitively define the speed of the front?

@C.Hamster intuitively it's the measure of how fast the solution is moving through space overtime

@C.Hamster thanks for your answer it really helps me!

Exactly, given that the solution is a fixed shape that moves in 1 direction through space, you can define the numerical speed as (how far has the shape moved)/(how long is the integration time).
